# How to integrate datatables in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, datatable

I need to intergrate datatable and load all the data into the Tkinter GUI in python.. Is it possible to load datatable in Tkinter?

Comment: I googled: "load database content into tkinter gui" and got many hits - it is possible and there a number of examples available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate and load data from datatable. To import the data from datatable you need the connector which connects your python code and database. If you are using MySQL/MariaDB database then there is a "mysql.connector" using which you can easily connect your database.